# Query only past events and only future events in the event calendar

Tags: the-events-calendar

after migrating my website to siteground I don't know why my event page doesn't work properly.
My past event list and future list are messed up. All list report all events future and past.

My code for future events is:

```
if (
    $post->post_type=='page' && 
    (
        $post->post_name=='eventi' ||
        $post->post_name=='events'
    )
) {  
    $events = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        )
    );
}
```

and code for past event is:

```
$past_events = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'posts_per_page'=>-1,
        'eventDisplay'=>'past',
        'post_type' => 'tribe_events'
    )
);
```

I tried a lot but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `eventDisplay` isn't (necessarily) recognized by `WP_Query`, as it's an argument added by the plugin. Consider using [`tribe_get_events()`](https://theeventscalendar.com/knowledgebase/k/using-tribe_get_events/) instead ([developer docs here](https://docs.theeventscalendar.com/reference/functions/tribe_get_events/).)

Answer (score 0):

**For Past events:**
I have used date functino according to the time zone. Another date can also be added to the wp query.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Winnipeg');
$date2 = date('y-m-d h:i');
$pastEvents = tribe_get_events( [
  'start_date'   => '2014-10-01 00:01',
  'end_date'   => $date2,
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
] );
```

**For Future events:**

```
$pastEvents = array(
  'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'order' => 'rand',
  'date_query' => array(
    'before' => 'today', // today can also be replaced by now
    'inclusive' => true
   )
);
```

for more details visit:
[date function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
[tribe_get_events](https://theeventscalendar.com/knowledgebase/k/using-tribe_get_events/)